# Is thought disorder directly treatable with pharmacotherapy?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, abnormal-psychology, clinical-psychology

Thought disorder is usually secondary to psychosis or schizophrenia. But there are those that have some form of thought disorder without any positive psychotic symptoms.

Is there any medication indicated directly for the treatment of thought disorder? Could it be treated using ADD stimulants? Atypical antipsychotics perhaps?

Comment: As required with all questions here, [prior research is required](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject.  What aspects of thought disorder do you believe could be treated directly with pharmacotherapy?  What makes you believe it would be possible?